# joomla module position

Tags: joomla, module, position

I have a template  that allows me to have diferent combinations of columns. My problem is if I had two columns on the right of main content, everything is fine. But, if I put only 1 column this 1 columns inherits the widh of the 2 columns, dont know why this happen.

You can see it here [layout with 2 columns and maincontent](http://sharkpt.com)

Now, click on "Salas de poker menu" and see the difference. 
After searching the files and trying to fix it myself, I found this code, maybe can help here:

```
$right_column_middle_class = ' oneCol';

if($this->modules('right_left and right_right')) {
$right_column_middle_class = ' twoCol';
}
if($this->getParam("cwidth_position", '') == 'style') {
// right column
if($this->modules('right_left and right_right')) {
     $gkRightLeft = $this->getParam('right2_column_width', '50'). '%';
     $gkRightRight = (100 - $this->getParam('right2_column_width', '50')) . '%';
}
// all columns
$left_column = $this->modules('left_top + left_bottom + left_left + left_right');
$right_column = $this->modules('right_top + right_bottom + right_left + right_right');

if($left_column && $right_column) {
     $gkRight = $this->getParam('right_column_width', '20'). '%';
}  elseif ( $right_column ) {
     $gkRight = $this->getParam('right_column_width', '20'). '%';
}
}
?>
```

Sorry I don´t know much php, and english is not so great also, must I insert something like if there is only right_right position then full with is 50%?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No one can help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seeing as the code says `$this->getParam`, there should be an option in the template manager for the width of the area you want to change.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yes there is! But whatever the value I put in the theme panel I have the same problem. If I put 50% no matter if i have 1 or two columns it will always be 50% of width of the whole website!     I think the solution is in that code write something like, if the is modules in only one column, then only show that column but widh half the size.

Comment: try adding in an amount in px rather then %
If you still have problems then I will be more than happy to take a look for you in the template manager

Comment: If you want to take a look, access the admin panel here http:sharkpt.com/manutencao/administrator. Login is username:demo password: demo. thanks for the help so far. That link is a testing site, we can talk in the forum if you prefer

Comment: Ok I have set the Right column width to 34% which works fine on the Salas de Poker page and I see what you mean now about it also making the Homepage right column smaller. So I would suggest you change the module position of "Jogadores" to the same position as the login, above or below the article. Sorry I couldnt be much help but they have coded this template very badly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10666/discussion-between-ricardo-ribeiro-and-charlie-lodder)